# Lettuce StatefulRedisConnection async command execution order

Tags: java, kotlin, redis, lettuce

I'm confused a bit about order of Redis command execution when using a Lettuce driver.
Examples use code like

```kotlin
private val cacheConnection: StatefulRedisConnection<String, String>

// (...)

cacheConnection.async().getset(keyStr, json)
cacheConnection.async().expire(keyStr, expireAfterWrite)
```

https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/issues/1627

https://www.baeldung.com/java-redis-lettuce

However, the documentation states

> good example is the async API. Every invocation on the async API **returns a Future (response handle) after the command is written to the netty pipeline**. A write to the pipeline does not mean, the command is written to the underlying transport. Multiple commands can be written without awaiting the response. Invocations to the API (sync, async and starting with 4.0 also reactive API) can be performed by multiple threads.

(https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/wiki/Pipelining-and-command-flushing)

This does not specify when the commands are put in the pipeline. Shouldn't I use `thenAccept` instead?

```kotlin
cacheConnection.async().getset(keyStr, json)
    .thenAccept { expire(keyStr, expireAfterWrite) }
```

That would mean that all these examples are wrong which is... improbable?

Can you please explain how does it work? Is execution order preservation just a systematic coincidence (ie an implementation detail)?

Comment: "This does not specify when the commands are put in the pipeline." Sure it does, "returns a Future after the command is written to the netty pipeline".

Comment: So it's not async? That would make no sense if an async method waited until operation is completed. No, it says that a Future is after the command is written. If I want something happen after a "Future", I use `thenAccept`

Comment: Unless... the Future is AFTER command is queued in pipeline, but BEFORE command is executed...

Comment: `Returns a Future after the command is written to the netty pipeline`. It's not saying anything about it being executed, the state of the `Future` will keep you updated on that.

Comment: O̶K̶ ̶s̶o̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶I̶ ̶r̶e̶a̶l̶l̶y̶ ̶w̶a̶n̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶m̶a̶k̶e̶ ̶a̶n̶o̶t̶h̶e̶r̶ ̶c̶a̶l̶l̶ ̶a̶f̶t̶e̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶m̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶e̶x̶e̶c̶u̶t̶e̶d̶,̶ ̶I̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶n̶o̶ ̶w̶a̶y̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶
After your comment edit it's clear, but it's not in the docs (or I missed it)

Comment: Of course you do, for example with any of the `thenXXX` methods, but do you need to? `Future` is the Java version of promises, so of course you'll return one from an async method.

Comment: I... think that I understand this now. This completely unexpected though, coming from kotlin coroutines world, I assume that an async method doesn't do **anything** synchronously. I'm used to think that calling two async method one after another says nothing about order of execution, whether it's "just" saving to a pipeline or executing commands.

In case of Redis, setting TTL before calling put would do nothing so an order must be guaranteed if all code examples are correct

Comment: The API is async, but the method call that returns the `Future` is synchronous, and since the operations are in a queue, the asynchronous operations retain order. They're only async wrt to the "main thread", not wrt each other.

Comment: "since the operations are in a queue" <- thanks, this is what was confusing me. When I call "fooAsync(); barAsync()" I assume it's the same as "barAsync(); fooAsync()".

Comment: Proof of above: implementation of CommandHandler::addToStack in lettuce. And if you look at RedisChannelHandler::dispatch, a LOT of stuff is happening synchronously. It's not like "start lambda on some thread in a pool and return promise of something happening",

Comment: Well you need to understand the differences between asynchronicity, concurrency and parallelism. Asynchronous does not equal parallel, and Kotlin's coroutines are just one way of handling concurrency.